# Power Automate - How to Update SharePoint list with Approval Response

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, approval, response

I have a Power Automate flow that triggers on a New Item, then Creates an Approval (2 custom responses - Approved/Rejected).  I've got it all set up so far.  the notification gets sent when an item is submitted in PowerApps (to SharePoint), and it allows the recipient to provide a response, reassign, add comments.  BUT, how can I update the SharePoint list with that response?  I have a Status column, and I want the Response (from Project manager) to then update that column.  I know how to use the Update Item action, but I don't know where the Response is logged.  When I add Update Item after Create an Approval, there isn't a clear option in the Dynamic Content for the Response.  "Outcome" or "Response" aren't in the Dynamic Content, so does that mean I need to Initialize/Set a variable to capture the response?  If so, how would that expression be?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have instructed to create an approval. If you need to return the outcome, you need to use Wait for an approval.

Wait for an approval
[image]